# Running Update Query via executeQuery

Tags: sql, oracle

We have some legacy code where we are still invoking **executeQuery** method of **PreparedStatement** to run an update sql , **executeQuery** method returns **ResultSet** object.
Now we have a requirement to take some action based on whether the update action resulted in any actual updation or not.

Wondering how can I understand from return **ResultSet** type , that it resulted in a successful updation or not.

Comment: [Check the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate())

Comment: Why are you using executeQuery instead of executeUpdate?

Comment: As i mentioned it's legacy code. Some scenarios we pass select statement some update statement. Update flow works in production since several years so syntactically it's not incorrect. As API is allowing so how we trap the update status that's the question.

Comment: "works in production since several years so syntactically it's not incorrect"  I've been in this business for 40 years.  Trust me when I say the landscape is littered with with code that "worked in production since several years".  That is code that just _happened_ to work, even though it was being used in a way that depended on undocumented and unintended behavior.  Then, one day a new release would change that undocumented behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ExecuteNonQuery instead, it returns the number of rows updated.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It's a generic method which sometime takes select and some times update statement. We can and should  change it , that part is clear. But provision is there in JDBC API as it is allowing update statement to pass in executeQuery method. How do we understand from output in the current code.

Comment: Then you I soupose that you should check documentation about ExecuteQuery.  
Perhaps ExecuteQuery returns in case of update/delete the info you need. 
I encourage you to change code and use ExecuteNonQyery wuen update statement is used.